# Is it possible to use ngrok or localtunnel to test local gRPC server?

Tags: grpc, ngrok, localtunnel

I am trying to create a tunnel to call my local gRPC server from a cloud machine for development/testing purposes. I have tried ngrok with HTTP and TCP and also localtunnel, but the client seems to just hang and doesn't return any error. Is this possible? Which protocol should I expose?

My gRPC client is running using Node and my server is using .Net Framework, and the channel is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if ngrok has http2. Try nghttp2 h2load.